# get mime type without mime_content_type or finfo_open

Tags: php, file

So, I have a client who is uber paranoid wanting stuff that he won't allow me access to. He has a very trimmed down version of PHP installed essentially gutting it to what he thinks is vital. That said I have a script that he wants done that is for uploading files.

I want to do some form of sanity checks to insure that the file is what it needs to be and thats all. So I am wondering if there is any special methods I can use that isn't `mime_content_type` or `finfo_open` as well as not specific to either supporting library. His PHP version is 5.6.x

Comment: I think your only option at this point is going to be to generate a while list of file extensions. Are you checking to see if a file is an image or pdf or something?

Comment: Should add that file extension does not necessarily = content type.  Its a best guess at most.

Comment: Do you have a list of valid content-types you wish to allow?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments on the PHP Documentation page, [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php#116793) was a suggested method.  I assume it would be running on linux in this case:

```
<?php
function detectFileMimeType($filename='')
{
    $filename = escapeshellcmd($filename);
    $command = "file -b --mime-type -m /usr/share/misc/magic {$filename}";

    $mimeType = shell_exec($command);

    return trim($mimeType);
}
?>
```

This also assumes he has given you access to shell_exec.  Now that I read your question more carefully that seems unlikely.  [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php#91646) post also explains a similar way to accomplish what you need without the benefit of those methods.

Comment: Good call, didn't think of tackling it like that. And this did work so bonus on that note as well. Appreciate it!

Comment: No problemo.  I think its a little strange he would lock down php but then leave shell_exec or system calls available.  I'd probably not let him know this is how you solved your problem ;)

Comment: @chris, you are not allowed to use `mime_content_type` but allowed to use the `shell_exec` function?!

Comment: Yea.. I don't think he's so much intentionally trying to lock me out of things more so than he is just trying to keep his idea of a lean install. So in that he has not included various modules I could have otherwise used. But wont give me the permissions to add them to the `php.ini` to load them in

Comment: The scripts I am writing require command line execution also, since some of what I am doing involves cron jobs that trigger ghost script and convert commands in the shell

Comment: @chris, and why the `mime_content_type` function is so dangerous that he blocked it?